# Can Intellij Idea be configured to break when a JUnit AssertionError occurs?

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

Can Intellij Idea be configured to break when a JUnit java.lang.AssertionError occurs during debugging?

I know that Intellij Idea supports the ability to break when exceptions occur during debugging, but I am not sure if this is possible for AssertionErrors.

This would be particularly useful when a large application context must be prepared before unit tests can be ran.

I searched, but could not find the answer to this question.

Here is how my Run > View Breakpoints... > Java Exception Breakpoints dialog is configured:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run a simple failing test and catch this kind of exception?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that. I have configured Run > View Breakpoints > Java Exception Breakpoints to break on Java exceptions. I am able to successfully break when an exception occurs. However, Intellij still does not break when a java.lang.AssertionError occurs. Is there a special setting that I need to configure to break on AssertionErrors too? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint, and adding `java.lang.AssertionError` to the class filter.

Comment: Hi Mike, I added java.lang.AssertionError to Class Filters, but this still did not cause Idea to break on the AssertionError. I have added a screenshot of by Breakpoints dialog for reference. Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my settings in this dialog. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I remembered the procedure incorrectly.  See my answer.

Comment: Hi Mike, Wow, Awesome! Your answer is correct. I can now break on AssertionErrors. I marked your answer as the answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the Breakpoints dialog, click the `+` button to add a new breakpoint, select "Java Exception Breakpoints" from the drop-down, and then enter `java.lang.AssertionError` as the exception class.