# IntelliJ doesn't break on Exceptions during full "tests" run?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I am working on a Gradle based Spring Boot/Java app using IntelliJ version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1
Build #IU-172.3544.35, built on July 31, 2017
Subscription is active until April 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
```

If I right click on the top level test directory in the project that houses the TestRunner tests and select the "Run Tests in project-test" option, I see numerous exceptions in the log file while the tests are executed.  However, IntelliJ never breaks when an Exception occurs.  I was hoping that the IDE would stop execution when an Exception occurs during a test and allow me to trace the code, like it does when simply running the project in debug mode.  (i.e. - normal non-test application launch).  To repeat, IntelliJ *does* break when an Exception occurs when running the application in debug mode.  Just not during the execution of the test classes that contain the @Test method annotations.

How do I get IntelliJ to stop when an Exception occurs so I can trace, during a run of the project test suite?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955273/can-intellij-idea-be-configured-to-break-when-a-junit-assertionerror-occurs)?

Comment: @glitch I want to break on all Exceptions, not just one particular Exception type like that question you referenced.

Comment: @RobertOschler see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-exception-breakpoints.html

Comment: Can you follow the approach described in that answer but do not apply the AssertionError class filter i.e. let IntelliJ break on *any* exception?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an IntelliJ problem; you should be telling Gradle and JUnit what you'd like to do.  Add this to your configuration and see if it helps:

```
test.ignoreFailures false
```